# A transcendental number from the diophantine equation $x+2y+3z=n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, transcendental-numbers

Let $\displaystyle n=1,2,3,\cdots.$ We denote by $D_n$ the number of non-negative integer solutions of the diophantine equation 
$$x+2y+3z=n$$

> Prove that 
>   $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{D_{2n+1}}
> $$
>   is a transcendental number.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts of your own on this problem? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Henning Makholm This is a problem from me (please correct my poor english! I will edit). Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to find a closed form for the sum which uses  $\sqrt{3}$, $\pi$  and $\pi^2$, and so is transcendental if $\pi$ is.

Comment: @Henry Good! Details ...

Comment: @OlivierOloa: So you came up with the problem yourself? what makes you think the sum _is_ transcendental, then?

Comment: @Henning Makholm I know the sum ...

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Then what is your question? It sounds like you already know all you're asking.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Why not consider it a (small) challenge?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Well, why not just ask "Find $D_n$" then? Once you know it, summing the series is really routine.

Comment: @CuriousGuest Not so 'routine'... Find $D_n$ is classic.

Comment: $D_n=round\left[\dfrac{(n+3)^2}{12}\right]$.  See [OEIS A001399](https://oeis.org/A001399) and [OEIS A000212](https://oeis.org/A000212); the latter gives the sum here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have not mistaken something,
$$ [x^{2n+1}]\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)} = \frac{(n+1)(n+3)}{3}, $$
when $n\equiv 0,2\pmod{3}$, and
$$ [x^{2n+1}]\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)} = \frac{(n+1)(n+3)+1}{3} $$
when $n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{D_{2n+1}}&=&\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{3}{(n+1)(n+3)}-\!\!\!\!\sum_{n\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!\!3}}\frac{3}{(n+1)(n+3)(n+2)^2}\\&=&\frac{9}{4}-\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{9}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{36}\left(27+2\pi\left(\pi+3\sqrt{3}\right)\right),\end{eqnarray*}$$
and we only need to show that $u=\pi(\pi+3\sqrt{3})$ is a trascendental number.

But if $u$ were algebraic, then
$$\pi = \frac{-3\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{27+4u}}{2}$$
would be algebraic too, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$
\displaystyle D_{n} = \left \lfloor \frac {(n+3)^2}{12} \right \rceil
$$
where $\lfloor x \rceil$ is the nearest integer to $x$. You can find a detailed proof [here](https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=denumerant%2Bbordelles) (first pdf link, **p.50**).
It gives
$$
D_{2n+1} = \left \lfloor \frac {(n+2)^2}{3} \right \rceil.
$$

As Jack D'Aurizio explained, we deduce that

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{D_{2n+1}}=\frac{3}{4} + \frac{\pi \sqrt{3}}{6} + \frac{\pi^2}{18} 
> $$

Since $\sqrt{3}$ is algebraic, this sum is transcendental as $\pi$ is.

Likewise, we obtain

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{D_{n}}= \frac{135}{36} - \frac{\pi \sqrt{3}}{6} + \frac{\pi^2}{18} +\frac{\pi \sqrt{3}}{3}\tan \left( \frac{\pi \sqrt{3}}{6} \right),
> $$
>   $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{D_{n}}=\frac{9}{4} - \frac{\pi \sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{\pi^2}{18} +\frac{\pi \sqrt{3}}{3}\tan \left( \frac{\pi \sqrt{3}}{6} \right).
> $$

For these two last sums, it seems rather difficult to prove they are transcendental, as we may suspect they are.